# Why would the column resize icon be changing to orange?

Tags: css, icons, cursor

[image]

The column resize icon keeps changing to the color orange? I definitely did not change the color of the icon, but I'm not seeing any reason why it would be changing. I think it could possibly happening due to the background color?
Any ideas on how I can ensure that it stays its default color of black?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the tour first. Then read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for debugging details. Pictures with code-lines are inacceptable!!

Comment: use `mix-blend-mode: difference` I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.